# A function to convert 0-2000 milliseconds to a double representing a fraction of a second

Tags: c, floating-point

```c
// ms is expected to be between 0 and 2000
// fakeDouble is expected to be {0, 0}
// uint64_t isn't used because it doesn't work with /NODEFAULTLIB when compiling 32-bit
void msToDouble(uint32_t ms, uint32_t* fakeDouble) {
    if (ms == 0) {
        return;
    } else if (ms >= 2000) {
        fakeDouble[1] = 0x40000000;
        return;
    }
    
    int exponent = 0;
    
    while (ms < 1000) {
        ms *= 2;
        exponent += 1;
    }
    
    fakeDouble[1] = (1023 - exponent) << 20;
    
    for (int bitPlace = 51; ms != 1000 && bitPlace >= 0; bitPlace--) {
        ms -= 1000 * (ms > 1000);
        ms *= 2;
        fakeDouble[bitPlace >= 32] |= (ms >= 1000) << (bitPlace - (32 * (bitPlace >= 32)));
    }
}
```

I read about compiling with the /NODEFAULTLIB option, and I'm planning on doing that with a small program I'm working on since it doesn't use much standard library stuff. This is a function I'll need to use due to not having access to atof or similar functions.

Comment: Why `uint32_t* fakeDouble`? Why not an actual `double`?

Comment: I just need to make the bit representation of a double.

Comment: Is there any reason you're not doing the obvious `x % 1000 / 1000.`?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat seems like the goal here is to learn how double represents number without using floating point arithmetics.

Comment: @justhalf Maybe, but OP should be explicit. My first guess was that they're thinking it'll be faster if they do it manually.

Comment: "*This is a function I'll need to use due to not having access to atof or similar functions*" -- I don't see what `atof` has to do with integer-to-fp conversion.  Arithmetic and type conversions are built into the language.  They do not depend on the standard library.  I suggest reserving custom code for stuff that actually requires it.

Comment: 2000ms is not a fraction of a second. If you want the fraction, use `ms % 1000`. Unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## random garbage in initial word

```
// fakeDouble is expected to be {0, 0}
```

This is insanity.
The code *needs* to implement this comment.
Either `assert` that caller supplied 64 zero bits,
or assign zeros upon entry.

```
        fakeDouble[1] = 0x40000000;
```

Relying on the `[0]` element to be zero is far too adventurous.
As written it is indeterminate what `double` value this function returns.
We strive to avoid Undefined Behavior.

Comment: Does this look okay? https://pastebin.com/1cnpMVp6

Comment: Assigning 64 zero bits up front is terrific, yes that looks okay. It is doing `fakeDouble[0] = 0`;
    `fakeDouble[1] = 0`

Comment: Note that _undefined behavior_ has a very specific meaning when it comes to the C programming language, usually shortened as **UB**. It's confusing if you use the same expression to just mean "indeterminate".

Answer (score 11):

### Missing header

`uint32_t` is not defined - we need to include `<stdint.h>` for this to compile.

### Unit tests

The tests are completely absent.

### Explanation

The rationale for returning a pair of integers instead of simply returning `ms / 1000.0` as a `double` is missing.

### Magic numbers

The code seems to assume a 64-bit IEEE double format.  Either we should be using the target platform's floating-point type, in which case we should include `<float.h>` and use the standard macros such as `DBL_RADIX` and `DBL_MANT_DIG`, or we should define the output format ourselves and define our own constants for the layout.

There's also an assumption that 1/1000.0 is not denormal.  That's more forgivable, bit it's worth a comment that this code won't work for arbitrary divisors, in case someone attempts to re-use the function in a different context.

Answer (score 11):

**Code fails *every time***

With `ms == 0`, code can return a non-zero *fake double* due to unassigned `fakeDouble[]`.

Non-zero `ms` errors approach 1 part in 10,000.

Robust code errors would be less than 1 part in 10<sup>15</sup>.

---

Sample test code

```
#include <stdio.h>

// Return error code
int msToDouble_int_test(uint32_t ms, int print) {
  union {
      double d;
      uint32_t fakeDouble[2];
  } u;
  msToDouble(ms, u.fakeDouble);
  double ref = ms/1000.0;
  if (ref != u.d) {
    static double worst = 0.0;
    double err = (u.d - ref)/ref;
    if (ms != 0  && err > worst) {
      worst = err;
    }
    if (print || err == worst) {
      printf("%5lu --> %-24.17g %-21a, expect %-24.17g %-21a   %.3g%%\n",
        (unsigned long)ms,u.d, u.d, ref, ref, err*100.0);
    }
    return 1;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Sample output

```
    0 --> 4.9406564584124654e-323  0x1.4p-1071          , expect 0                        0x0p+0                  inf%
    1 --> 0.0009999999999999998    0x1.0624dd2f1a9fbp-10, expect 0.001                    0x1.0624dd2f1a9fcp-10   -2.17e-14%
    2 --> 0.0019999999999999996    0x1.0624dd2f1a9fbp-9 , expect 0.002                    0x1.0624dd2f1a9fcp-9    -2.17e-14%
    3 --> 0.0030000004843486728    0x1.89374fefbfffbp-9 , expect 0.0030000000000000001    0x1.89374bc6a7efap-9    1.61e-05%
    4 --> 0.0040000006408717993    0x1.0624dfefbfffbp-8 , expect 0.0040000000000000001    0x1.0624dd2f1a9fcp-8    1.6e-05%
    5 --> 0.0050000026822090106    0x1.47ae1fffffffbp-8 , expect 0.0050000000000000001    0x1.47ae147ae147bp-8    5.36e-05%
    6 --> 0.0060000009834766345    0x1.89374fffffffbp-8 , expect 0.0060000000000000001    0x1.89374bc6a7efap-8    1.64e-05%
    7 --> 0.0070000030100345568    0x1.cac08fffffffbp-8 , expect 0.0070000000000000001    0x1.cac083126e979p-8    4.3e-05%
    8 --> 0.0080000013113021764    0x1.0624dfffffffbp-7 , expect 0.0080000000000000002    0x1.0624dd2f1a9fcp-7    1.64e-05%
    9 --> 0.0090000033378600987    0x1.26e97fffffffbp-7 , expect 0.0089999999999999993    0x1.26e978d4fdf3bp-7    3.71e-05%
   10 --> 0.010000005364418021     0x1.47ae1fffffffbp-7 , expect 0.01                     0x1.47ae147ae147bp-7    5.36e-05%
   11 --> 0.011000007390975943     0x1.6872bfffffffbp-7 , expect 0.010999999999999999     0x1.6872b020c49bap-7    6.72e-05%
   22 --> 0.022000014781951887     0x1.6872bfffffffbp-6 , expect 0.021999999999999999     0x1.6872b020c49bap-6    6.72e-05%
   35 --> 0.035000026226043666     0x1.1eb85fffffffbp-5 , expect 0.035000000000000003     0x1.1eb851eb851ecp-5    7.49e-05%
   65 --> 0.065000057220458915     0x1.0a3d7fffffffbp-4 , expect 0.065000000000000002     0x1.0a3d70a3d70a4p-4    8.8e-05%
  125 --> 0.12500011920928941      0x1.00000fffffffbp-3 , expect 0.125                    0x1p-3                  9.54e-05%
  250 --> 0.25000023841857905      0x1.00000ffffffffp-2 , expect 0.25                     0x1p-2                  9.54e-05%
  500 --> 0.50000047683715809      0x1.00000ffffffffp-1 , expect 0.5                      0x1p-1                  9.54e-05%
 1000 --> 1.0000009536743162       0x1.00000ffffffffp+0 , expect 1                        0x1p+0                  9.54e-05%
 2000 --> 2.0000019073486324       0x1.00000ffffffffp+1 , expect 2                        0x1p+1                  9.54e-05%
Error count 2001
```

---

**Alternate**

Do the division using wide integer math to form the quotient.  Below keeps track powers of 2 separately. Then form the floating point *fake double*.

If code adjusts the `dividend / divisor` prior to division and pays attention to rounding, there is **no error** for all `uint32_t`  values [0 ... 0xFFFFFFFF].

```
#define DBL_IMPLIED_BIT (1ull << 52)

// Divide an integer by 1000 and form a floating point quotient
void msToDouble(uint32_t ms, uint32_t *fakeDouble) {
  unsigned long long dividend = ms;
  unsigned long long divisor = 1000;
  unsigned long long quotient = 0;
  unsigned long long expo = 0;
  if (dividend) {
    expo = (1024-1) + 52;  // Exponent for 1.0, scaled
    // Adjust dividend to maximize quotient precision.
    while (dividend < 0x8000000000000000u) {
      dividend <<= 1;
      expo--;
    }
    // Adjust divisor to maximize quotient precision.
    while (divisor % 2 == 0) {
      divisor >>= 1;
      expo--;
    }
    // Do the division
    quotient = dividend/divisor;
    while (quotient <  DBL_IMPLIED_BIT) {
      quotient <<= 1;
      expo--;
    }
    // Round based on last bit shifted out
    unsigned last_bit_out = 0;
    while (quotient >= DBL_IMPLIED_BIT*2) {
      last_bit_out = quotient & 1;
      quotient = quotient >> 1;
      expo++;
    }
    quotient += last_bit_out;
    // Detect carry
    if (quotient >=  DBL_IMPLIED_BIT*2) {
      quotient = quotient >> 1;
      expo++;
    }
    // Lop off implied bit
    quotient -= DBL_IMPLIED_BIT;
  }
  quotient |= expo << 52;
  fakeDouble[1] = quotient >> 32;
  fakeDouble[0] = quotient;
}
```

Comment: "Robust code errors would be less than 1 part in 10^15" I'm curious, where did you get that number from?

Comment: @Mast Typical [`double`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) encodes most values with a 53-bit precision: 1 part in 2^53. This is akin to at least 15 decimal digits.  I would expect `ms/1000.0` per a robust `msToDouble()` to be correct to at least that many significant digits.